# Inno Setup installation for standard user

Tags: inno-setup

```
Source: "c:\Dropbox\word\EzPaste028012\2010Install\FilesToInstall-Common\DAS_AX_Knob.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\EzPaste" ; Flags: regserver sharedfile
```

My installer works properly for administrators without any problem but standard users get an error 
[image]

It looks that the error occurs because the Standard User has no rights in the admin **User** where the the installation occurs. Is there a way to fix this or cause the installation to take place in a folder form which the Standard User may register the components?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `sharedfile` flag at all? You seem to install the file to user and application specific folder.

Comment: I have removed the sharedfile flag but still get errors while trying to register the ddl

Comment: "Get errors" is useless information. What errors?

Comment: Sorry, The error : "c:/user/standard user/appd
data/microsoft/addins/ezpaste/das_knob.dll" , regservfail, code 0x5

Comment: Can you post an exact and complete error message? Or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: [Here the link to the print screen](http://metrics-institute.com/avibenita/EzPaste/Err3.png}

Comment: Can you also show us a log file of the installer?

Comment: [Here is the the log](http://metrics-institute.com/avibenita/EzPaste/INST-LOG.TXT)

Comment: I do not think the information you posted are enough for us to reproduce the problem. There is, in general, no problem registering a DLL by an installer executed by a non-privileged account. There has to be something specific about your installer and/or your machine. 1) I consider your original problem (with shared file flag) solved, and as such this question as closed. Consider accepting my answer, if it helped you. 2) Post a new question with [mcve]. But make sure you test the example installer it on a different machine first to verify that it really reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to install the DLL to user- and application-specific folder. So I do not think you actually need the [`sharedfile` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=sharedfile).

---

Anyway, to register a DLL in the `SharedDLLs` (stored in the `HKLM`), you need Administrator privileges. There's no way around that.

All you can do is not to register the DLL, if you are not installing as an Administrator.

Create two `[Files]` entries, one with the `sharedfile` flag and one without. And use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) and the [`IsAdmin` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmin) (or [`IsAdminInstallMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode) or `IsAdminLoggedOn` [in older versions]) to select an appropriate entry.

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\Dropbox\word\EzPaste028012\2010Install\FilesToInstall-Common\DAS_AX_Knob.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\EzPaste"; Flags: regserver sharedfile; Check: IsAdmin
[Files]
Source: "c:\Dropbox\word\EzPaste028012\2010Install\FilesToInstall-Common\DAS_AX_Knob.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\EzPaste"; Flags: regserver; Check: not IsAdmin
```

Comment: I have removed the sharedfile flag but still get errors while trying to register the dll